# How to get value from multidimensional array value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
    Array
(
    [updateCategories] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 3
                            [position] => 2
                            [product_id] => 8
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 4
                            [position] => 11
                            [product_id] => 8
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 3
                            [position] => 4
                            [product_id] => 39
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 4
                            [position] => 9
                            [product_id] => 8
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 3
                            [position] => 6
                            [product_id] => 41
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 11
                            [position] => 7
                            [product_id] => 8
                        )
```

The above array is my output array but I need to get all `cat_id` of `product_id=8`. How can I do this?

Comment: iterate over the array and find it...

Answer (score 1):

Can handle this by doing something like this

```
$matching_products = array();
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    if($value['product_id'] == 8) {
        $matching_products[] = $value['cat_id'];
    }
}
```

which'll leave you with an array of cat ids that have a product id of 8

Answer (score 1):

```
$newarr = array();
foreach( $arr['updateCategories']['products'] as $myarr)
{
  if($myarr['product_id'] == 8)
  $newarr[] =  $myarr['cat_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution is

```
$result = array();
foreach($yourArray['updateCategories']['products'] as $product)
  if($product['product_id] == 8)
    $product[] = $product['cat_id'];
```

where `$yourArray` is the array which dump you have published.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($products as $key => $value) 
{
    if($value['product_id'] == 8) 
    {
        $arr[] = $key;

    }
}
print_r($arr); // <-- this should output the array of products with key as 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 foreach($array['updateCategories']['products'] as $product) {
      if(isset($product['product_id']) && $product['product_id']==8) {
        //do anything you want i am echoing
         echo $product['cat_id'];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)**.

```
function filterProducts($product) {
    return ($product['product_id'] == 8);
}

$myProducts = array_filter(
    $myArray['updateCategories']['products'], 
    'filterProducts'
);
```

Where `$myArray` is the array displayed in your post.

Comment: But if you need just array of `cat_id`s as it is mentioned in question you have to iterate through all array again.

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to retrieve all of the cat_id's from a given product_id.  This function yields an object that can be iterated over to retrieve all the values it contains.

```
<?PHP 

    public function GetCatIdsByProductId($productId)
    {

        foreach($updateCategories=>products as $key=>$product)
        {
            if (isset($product=>product_id) && $product=>product_id == 8)
            {
                yield $product=>cat_id;
            }
        }
    }

    //Usage
    $catIds = GetCatIdsByProductId(8);
    var_dump($catIds);
```

A more generic version of this function can be constructed to retrieve a given key from a comparison on a given property value.

```
    public function GetPropertyByPropertyComparison(array $list, $propRet, $propCompare, $compValue)
    {

        foreach($list as $key=>$product)
        {
            if (isset($product=>{$propCompare}) && $product=>{$propCompare} == $compValue)
            {
                yield $product=>{$propRet};
            }
        }
    }

    //usage
    $cats = GetPropertyByPropertyComparison($updateCategories=>products, "cat_id", "product_id", 8);
    var_dump($cats);
?>
```